# If the polynomial f(x) with real coefficients is non-negative for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then all its real zeros have even multiplicity

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm dealing with this problem that says that if $f(x)$ with real coefficients is non-negative for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then there exists the polynomials $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ from  $\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $f(x)$ can be written in the form of $f(x)=f_1^2(x)
+f_2^2(x)$

The solution in my book says that all its real zeros have even multiplicity. Can someone tell me why is that?

Comment: $n$ odd, $p(a)\ne0$ implies $(x-a)^np(x)$ changes sign at $a$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that we have a root of $f(x)$ at $x = \alpha$. So we have $f(x) = (x-\alpha)^k Q(x)$, where $Q$ does not have a root at $\alpha$, and we must show that $k$ is even. Since $Q$ does not have a root at $\alpha$, its value at $\alpha$ is nonzero. But if $k$ is odd, the sign of $(x-\alpha)^k$ is different on either side of $\alpha$, and so the sign of $(x-\alpha)^k Q(x)$ is also different on either side of $\alpha$, implying that $f$ is not always positive. This is a contradiction, and so we conclude that $k$ is even.

Comment: This is really a proof by contrapositive, not by contradiction.

Comment: @Bernard That's true, although both are equivalent here.

Comment: @auscrypt So do we suppose that $Q(x)$ is always non-negative?

Comment: @J.Dane Not necessarily; all we care about is that the sign of $Q(x)$ is the same on either side of $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh yes I got it because if the sign it's not the same then $\alpha$ would be a root of $Q(x)$

Answer (score 2):

Roots of polynomials correspond to linear factors. A double root is a root of the derivative too. A root with multiplicity $k$ is a root of the first $k-1$ derivatives. That means that near the root $r$ the polynomial behaves like $(x-r)^k$. When $k$ is odd that function crosses the $x$-axis.